# Why std::string append is not overloaded on rval ref?

Tags: c++, stdstring, rvalue-reference, stdoptional

I'm familiar, that the `append` in `std::string` returns `std::string&` and therefore it do not qualify to be moved from, so the result will not be moved.

```cpp
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string s = std::string("A").append("B");
    return s.size();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M63aWW

```cpp
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string s = std::move(std::string("A").append("B"));
    return s.size();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jTnsac

There you can see, that the latter example will produce one fewer allocation and therefore in this case it is better to move something that may looks like a temporary. My question is why they (the committee) do not add simple overload on `&&` to make the result of `append` either `std::string&`, or `std::string&&` depending on the context? I mean something similar to `std::optional` is doing with [`value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value). Is there a example that will prove such optimization bogus?

Comment: Can you post an example where this would actually be useful? auto res = std::string("A").append("B"); dosent really make sense.

Comment: @Cortex Yes it doesn't make sense, but when you are trying to concatenate few strings, that may be quite large you want to reallocate as little as possible. And `append` will reuse the buffer, so there will be less allocations overall.

Comment: Workaround: `std::string s = std::move(std::string("A").append("B"));` but big meh to all of it. It's just not a compelling use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is covered in [P1165R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1165r1.html), the rules for allocator propagation for `basic_string`’s `operator+` are complex and a root of inconsistencies over different library implementations.

> #### Make stateful allocator propagation more consistent for operator+(basic_string)
>
> [...] Allocator propagation for `basic_string`’s `operator+` is haphazard, inconsistent, and a source of implementation divergence. Let's make them consistent. [...]

P1165R1 has been accepted for C++20.

The `append()` member function does not have the same semantics, is not as heavily overloaded and does not suffer from the same *”haphazardness ...”* as `operator+` (prior to P1165R1). There would be no reason for the former to join the domain of the latter; `basic_string` is already a monster of a container (which is not the case for your counter-example `optional`, which is not a container in the standardese sense, even if it has semantics similar to a stl container).

Answer (score 6):

You can't simply add an `&&` overload. You'd have to make the original function `&` too. And that's potentially a breaking change.

All that for very little gain. Since `append()` modifies the source string and returns `*this` more for chaining rather than assigning the result to anything else, the code you wrote is unidiomatic. If you want that, use `+`, which is the idiomatic form of building a string for an expression result, and already has the requisite overloads to be efficient:

```
auto s = "A"s + "B";
```

Comment: I have two things on that. Here `"A"s + "B"`, but as the strings get larger and there are more than two strings, this will reallocate the buffer on every single `+`, making it a bit suboptimal. How will the addition of `&` breaks code, when there will also be `&&` overload? I do not get that.

Comment: @koscelansky Check [overloads 6-12](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) for `operator+` - they do the moving internally.